# Can you change the size of chunks on minio ? and how does minio chunk?

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

I have found that minio's chunks are at least 5mb. Is there a way to change the part size ?

Comment: If you're talking about S3 Multipart uploads, then the size of all individual parts of an upload [must be at least 5MiB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/qfacts.html) (except the last part).  So, no matter what you do, the parts will always be at least 5MiB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide `chunkSize` to your `minio` client config:

```
import { Client } from 'minio'
import config from '../util/config'

export default new Client({
    endPoint: config.storage.host,
    port: config.storage.port,
    useSSL: config.storage.useSsl,
    accessKey: config.storage.accessKey,
    secretKey: config.storage.secretKey,
    partSize: 30 * 1024 * 1024,
})
```

Comment: is there no parametter on minio to change the chunk nomatter , how you send the file ? either from minio client itself or S3 api ?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. If you add some explanation - what your purpose then some can help you.

Comment: Setting shard size on bucket / server level could avoid having to deal with too many files. Trialing MinIO I had 40TB spread over 16 drives and after performance nose-dived after a month, I decided to delete the contents to reset MinIO – it takes ~60 minutes to delete the 2,5TB per drive, indicating the files are too many and too small for regular HDDs to deal with at scale.